# How do I make a modal FileChooserDialog using PyGOobject

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, gobject

I'm trying to make a modal FileChooserDialog using PyGObject.

The example at https://github.com/sebp/PyGObject-Tutorial/blob/master/examples/filechooserdialog_example.py works as expected, except that when the file chooser dialog is shown, I can still use the main window (including clicking the button to open a second dialog).

I've tried adding `flags=Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL` when creating the dialog (line 23), but that doesn't work.  I get no error, but I can still open a second dialog without closing the first one.

If I use a MessageDialog with the MODAL flag, it works exactly as expected.  But I need a file chooser.

Is there any quick solution or am I better off rolling my own Dialog that contains a FileChooser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something is wrong. What OS are you using? What version of GTK+?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and python-gobject 3.12.0-1ubuntu1.

Comment: It seems like a bug in the version of GTK+/GObject that you're using as the dialog behaves itself on Ubuntu 15.10 with GTK+ 3.16.7.